# QMF Turning Sequence Number Results into their own columns without PIVOT

Tags: sql

I'm sorry, I'm new and have almost no training. I've been searching for a few days on this and maybe I'm just not using the correct terms...

Using QMF for Windows.

I have 3 columns in my ADDRESSTABLE table - address identifier codes, address line sequence numbers and their corresponding address lines. ADR_CODE, SEQ_NO, ADRS_LINE.

Each address record has between 3 and 5 lines, and thusly, 3 to 5 sequence numbers. So, when I pull a query for address identifier codes, I get 3-5 repetitions of the address identifier code. Like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ADR_CODE, A.SEQ_NO, A.ADRS_LINE
FROM ADDRESSTABLE A
WHERE (A.ADR_CODE LIKE 'A%')
```

And I get:

```
ADR_CODE    SEQ_NO  ADRS_LINE
AAAA    1   JOHN DOE
AAAA    2   123 HAPPY STREET
AAAA    3   ANYWHERE, NY
AAAA    4   12345
AABB    1   234 MAIN STREET
AABB    2   SOMEWHERE, MN
AABB    3   34567
ACDE    1   MR PINK
ACDE    2   21 RESERVOIR RD
ACDE    3   APT 4
ACDE    4   LOS ANGELES
ACDE    5   90210
```

And I figured out that if I do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ADR_CODE, MIN(A.SEQ_NO CONCAT A.ADRS_LINE) AS 
"FIRST ADDRESS LINE", MAX(A.SEQ_NO CONCAT A.ADRS_LINE) AS
"LAST ADDRESS LINE"
FROM ADDRESSTABLE A
WHERE (A.ADR_CODE LIKE 'A%')
ORDER BY A.ADR_CODE ASC
GROUP BY A.ADR_CODE
```

I get:

```
ADR_CODE    FIRST ADDRESS LINE  LAST ADDRESS LINE
AAAA        1JOHN DOE           412345
AABB        1234 MAIN STREET    334567
ACDE        1MR PINK            590210
```

My question is, how do I get the rest of those in between lines? MIN+1 and MAX-1 is illegal, MIN(A.SEQ_NO +1... and MAX(A.SEQ_NO-1... is illegal. I'm stuck and I don't want to use PIVOT because I want this whole thing to be part of a larger query. In short, My query should end up with about 7000 rows of freight records - each with their own address in a line - instead of 7000 rows*(3 to 5 address lines per record).Thank you, James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not exactly a PIVOT, will a multiple join to same address table work for you as ...

```
SELECT 
      A.ADR_CODE, 
      A.ADRS_LINE as AdrLine1,
      A2.ADRS_LINE as AdrLine2,
      A3.ADRS_LINE as AdrLine3,
      COALESCE( A4.ADRS_LINE, "" ) as AdrLine4,
      COALESCE( A5.ADRS_LINE, "" ) as AdrLine5
   FROM 
      ADDRESSTABLE A
         JOIN ADDRESSTABLE A2
            ON A.ADR_CODE = A2.ADR_CODE
            AND A2.SEQ_NO = 2
         JOIN ADDRESSTABLE A3
            ON A.ADR_CODE = A3.ADR_CODE
            AND A3.SEQ_NO = 3
         LEFT JOIN ADDRESSTABLE A4
            ON A.ADR_CODE = A4.ADR_CODE
            AND A4.SEQ_NO = 4
         LEFT JOIN ADDRESSTABLE A5
            ON A.ADR_CODE = A5.ADR_CODE
            AND A5.SEQ_NO = 5
   WHERE
          A.ADR_CODE LIKE 'A%'
      AND A.SEQ_NO = 1
   ORDER BY
      A.ADR_CODE
```

Since the query is applied to the address table for only sequence #1, that will keep distinct adr_code entires for you since you are not getting the possible 2-5 address lines.

NOW comes the JOINs.  I rejoin to same address table on the same adr_code key, but for each one additionally only for that particular address line... applying LEFT-JOIN for 4 and 5 since you stated 1-3 are always and 4-5 are only POSSIBLE (also applied coalesce() to prevent NULLs).

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you. I had no idea about A2, A3 etc. Now, hopefully, I can give my boss the answer she's looking for tomorrow.

Comment: @user3026309, great... and just FYI as a newbie to the site.  When someone offers a good solution, you can up-arrow their solution as good idea, or you got something out of it.  Additionally, if its an answer that SOLVES your problem, you can click the check mark next to the answer so others know it has been solved.

Comment: @user3026309, also, the "A2" through "A5" are "alias" references so you can see here that you can use the same table multiple times in the same query.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp it seems to be working. I clicked the checkmark, but it won't let me up-arrow until I have 15 reputation. But thanks again.